# Ansible deploying Azure Function

Tags: azure, function, deployment, ansible

Anyone got a good source (with examples) on how to deploy Azure Functions using Ansible?

I've read the official documentation on azure_rm_functionapp, but still pretty vague on how Ansible references the code that needs deployed...

Thanks

Comment: fairly certain ansible doesnt deploy code to the function app, it only deploys the app itself

Comment: @Tester_123, any update on this issue, could you deploy your code now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use Ansible and Azure Pipelines, you could refer to this blog:[Automating Infrastructure Deployments in the Cloud with Ansible and Azure Pipelines](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/ansible/).

As for other resource control, for now the ansible doesn't support specify Local Git deployment option or other resource.

So may be you could use [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest) or [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) to deploy your code. The below is some sample:

**az functionapp deployment source config-zip**

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip \
-g {myRG}} -n {myAppName} \
--src {zipFilePathLocation}
```

Functions Core Tools Deployment (project files)

```
func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We will probably use Ansible to deploy the function app, then use the Azure cli to deploy the actual code to the function. I think you can invoke Azure cli from Ansible, using Ansible shell module, so that's how I imagine we will do it. Thanks.